# Creating APK issue React Native with Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Hi I started learning react native with expo.

Writing code and using it fastly with my phone, it works well.
One thing is not well for me is creating apk. I searched and found "expo build:android" to create apk.It creates but takes long.Also giving error when try to install the apk like

"You may not have proper app for viewing this content apk" and the apk size is "45mb".
How can I create apk  with less size and time.

Thank you

The app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Some App",
    "slug": "some-app",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myapprandomname.myapprandomname"
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I can't create apk

Comment: Anyone  to help?

Answer (score 1):

You may try `expo build:android -t app-bundle`